# Parallel database calls using Java 8 streams and CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future

I would like to replicate and parallelize the following behavior with Java 8 streams:

```
for (animal : animalList) {
        // find all other animals with the same breed
        Collection<Animal> queryResult = queryDatabase(animal.getBreed());

        if (animal.getSpecie() == cat) {
            catList.addAll(queryResult);
        } else {
            dogList.addAll(queryResult);
        }
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
final Executor queryExecutor =
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Math.min(animalList.size(), 10),
                new ThreadFactory(){
                    public Thread newThread(Runnable r){
                        Thread t = new Thread(r);
                        t.setDaemon(true);
                        return t;
                    }
                });

List<CompletableFuture<Collection<Animal>>> listFutureResult =  animalList.stream()
        .map(animal -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> queryDatabase(animal.getBreed()), queryExecutor))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Animal> = listFutureResult.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .flatMap(subList -> subList.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1 - I'm not sure how to split the stream so that I can get 2 different animal lists, one for cats and one for dogs.

2 - does this solution look reasonable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, consider just using

```
List<Animal> result = animalList.parallelStream()
    .flatMap(animal -> queryDatabase(animal.getBreed()).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

even if it won’t give you the desired concurrency of up to ten. The simplicity might compensate it. Regarding the other part, it’s as easy as

```
Map<Boolean,List<Animal>> result = animalList.parallelStream()
    .flatMap(animal -> queryDatabase(animal.getBreed()).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(animal -> animal.getSpecie() == cat));
List<Animal> catList = result.get(true), dogList = result.get(false);
```

In case you have more species than just cats and dogs, you may use `Collectors.groupingBy(Animal::getSpecie)` to get a map from species to list of animals.

---

If you insist on using your own thread pool, a few things can be improved:

```
Executor queryExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Math.min(animalList.size(), 10),
    r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });
List<Animal> result =  animalList.stream()
    .map(animal -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(animal.getBreed())
        .thenApplyAsync(breed -> queryDatabase(breed), queryExecutor))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
    .flatMap(cf -> cf.join().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your `supplyAsync` variant required capturing the actual `Animal` instance, creating a new `Supplier` for each animal. In contrast, the function passed to `thenApplyAsync` is invariant, performing the same operation for each parameter value. The code above assumes that `getBreed` is a cheap operation, otherwise, it wouldn’t be hard to pass the `Animal` instance to `completedFuture` and perform `getBreed()` with the async function instead.

The `.map(CompletableFuture::join)` can be replaced by a simple chained `.join()` within the `flatMap` function. Otherwise, if you prefer method references, you should use them consistently, i.e. `.map(CompletableFuture::join).flatMap(Collection::stream)`.

Of course, this variant also allows using `partitioningBy` instead of `toList`.

---

As a final note, if you invoke `shutdown` on the executor service after use, there is no need to mark the threads as daemon:

```
ExecutorService queryExecutor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Math.min(animalList.size(),10));
Map<Boolean,List<Animal>> result =  animalList.stream()
    .map(animal -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(animal.getBreed())
        .thenApplyAsync(breed -> queryDatabase(breed), queryExecutor))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
    .flatMap(cf -> cf.join().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(animal -> animal.getSpecie() == cat));
List<Animal> catList = result.get(true), dogList = result.get(false);
queryExecutor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Hey Holger, thanks for your thorough and clear explanation :) I am trying to understand the difference in behavior between my implementation (which uses a stream to get a list of CompletableFutures then another stream to get the values from the CompletableFutures) and your implementation which does .join() in the same stream. Do you think you can give me a short explanation? Also if I want to do updateDatabase() instead of queryDatabase() is .map(...) still recommended or should I use .forEach()? updateDatabase() would return nothing (void)

Comment: There is no difference; I just omitted the intermediate local variable. It still consists of two Stream operations with a temporary `List`. If you want to wrap the `updateDatabase() ` in a `CompletableFuture` to be able to await its completion, `map` still is the way to go.

Comment: I'm just thinking about the behavior again and I'm kind of confused. If there  are more items in the stream than the number of threads, how can we perform the first part of the stream operation? animal -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(animal.getBreed())
        .thenApplyAsync(breed -> queryDatabase(breed), queryExecutor))                     wouldn't we run out of threads before getting through each item? What happens then?

Comment: That depends on the particular executor. So when we use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(…)`, we have to consider [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-): “*Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared **unbounded queue**. At any point, at most `nThreads` threads will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, **they will wait in the queue** until a thread is available*”

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. What does that mean for the second part of the operation .flatMap(cf -> cf.join().stream()) ? Does it also get queued up so that it executes after the thread starts? I guess the confusion is that it seems like some of the second stream needs to run (i.e. the .join() ) before the first stream finishes which is weird because the two streams are separated by a .collect